# Vue.js: Add "_delete" element when removing element from v-for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have some elements, showing through `v-for` directive. Each of these elements has "Remove" button. When I click it, I deletw element from array with `state.items.splice(payload.id, 1);` code. Bu I also need an hidden input which will indicate to server  that element has been destroyed.
In Ruby on Rails it is

```
<input type="hidden" name="order[line_items_attributes][<ID>][_delete]" value="1" />
```

How can I add this element?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why do you need hidden input and how will it help?

Comment: In the backend app is running on Ruby on Rails. It has special behaviour for  nested form elements. The main form that I'm editing is for shop Order model. Order has many Items in cart. Items is the nested model. And for removing some item from cart, I need to send "_destroy" attribute in request for that item. But how to do that, if any information about item getting removed from state?

Comment: You can do this at same place where you are doing `state.items.splice(payload.id, 1);`. Please add more relevant code if this not suits.

Comment: Instead of deleting the element from the array, maybe you could set a `deleted` flag and then inside your `v-for`, generate a hidden `input` instead of a regular `input` when `delete == true`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand well your question, but here is my response anyway.

Imagine you have the following template:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.name }} <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteItem(item)">Delete</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, you can use a `deleteItem()` method that you must define into your component:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'First Item'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Second Item'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        deleteItem (item) {
            this.$http({
                url: '/api/items/' + item.id,
                method: 'delete'
            }).then( response => {
                // Do something here if you want
            }, response => {
                // Or here if you want to handle an error
            })

            let index = this.items.indexOf(item)
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }

    }
}
```